# Incorrect result when using %d placeholder in a pow() function in C

Tags: c, printf, pow, conversion-specifier, internal-representation

I'm trying to finish some basic coding exercise and I have already figured out how to fix it but I would just really like to understand what's going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void) {
    int first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sumOne, sumTwo, product;

    printf("Enter integer 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &first);
    printf("Enter integer 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &second);
    printf("Enter integer 3: ");
    scanf("%d", &third);
    printf("Enter integer 4: ");
    scanf("%d", &fourth);
    printf("Enter integer 5: ");
    scanf("%d", &fifth);

    sumOne = first + second;
    sumTwo = third + fourth;

    printf("Result = %d", pow ((sumOne * sumTwo), fifth));

    return 0;

    
}
```

I have been reading and I found out that pow provides a double result. I found that by changing the placeholder on the last printf() statement to %.0f, I get the desired result. Reason why I used %d is because I didn't want to get decimals in the output. I could also modify the data type and to double instead of int and just limit the decimals again on the final result.

I think my question is why have I been getting incorrect result with the use of %d as placeholder? Thank you.

Comment: `printf` requires the type specifier and the corresponding variable argument to match. If you want to use `%d`, cast the result of `pow` to an `int`.

Comment: For integer powers, don't use the floating point `pow` function, create your own. But beware of possible overflow.

Comment: If you only want to print the integer portion of a floating point value, use `%.0f` or `%.0lf`

Answer (score 2):

The function `pow` is declared like

```
double pow(double x, double y);
```

That is its return type is double. So you need to write using the conversion specifier `f` instead of `d`

```
printf("Result = %f", pow ((sumOne * sumTwo), fifth));
```

> I think my question is why have I been getting incorrect result with
> the use of %d as placeholder?

double numbers usually occupy 8 bytes (objects of the type int usually occupy 4 bytes) and have internal representation that differ from the internal representation of integers.

You could cast the result of the call of pow to the type `int` and in this case use the conversion specifier `d`.

```
printf("Result = %d", ( int )pow ((sumOne * sumTwo), fifth));
```

Or you could round the result of the call of pow before outputting it as an integer.

Comment: I'm ok with the first part of your answer. But not the second. If it is really important that the exponentiation is integer (and printed with ``%d``) then op should not use ``pow`` at all. ``pow(a,b)`` is basically ``exp(b*log(a))``.

Comment: So, not only is uses floating point operation that may be costly (ok, nowadays, nobody cares anymore). But more importantly, it is a float. So, for example, what if the result is ``255.9999999999999999999`` as it could be?

Comment: Correct answer to the 2nd part has been given in comments to the question: "don't use pow for integer". And if you really must, and want to print only the integer part, use "%.0f"

Comment: @chrslg The question is about conversion specifiers and why you may not use the conversion specifier d with floating numbers in calls of printf.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. That is why I upvoted. But, again, casting 255.9999999999999 would not lead to the wanted output.

Comment: @chrslg and use `round()`.

Comment: Sure. Let go. I obviously don't explain myself correctly if people think that I need to know about round. I was talking about the ``(int)`` solution. I don't really need to know how to solve the problem myself

Answer (score 0):

A `printf` conversion specification generally tells `printf` two things: what type of argument to expect and what to do with it.

For example:

- `%d` says expect an `int` argument and print it as a decimal numeral.
- `%c` says expect an `int` argument, convert it to an `unsigned char`, and print the character with that code.
- `%f` says expect a `double` argument and print it in decimal notation with six digits after the decimal point.
- `%e` says expect a `double` argument and print it in scientific notation.

The conversion specification needs to tell `printf` the type of the argument because nothing in the regular C function-call mechanism tells the called function what the argument types are. A function has to be either defined with certain types or it has to be told what the types are through some other mechanism. For `printf`, that mechanism is the format string.

When you pass the result of `pow`, you pass a `double` argument, but `%d` tells `printf` to expect an `int` argument. Since these are different types, represented with different encoding methods, and may be passed in different places in the processor or memory, `printf` is unable to find and decode the argument you passed. The C standard does not define the behavior when you pass an argument of the wrong type for a `printf` conversion specification.

Answer (score 0):

> I think my question is why have I been getting incorrect result with the use of %d as placeholder? Thank you.

`%d` expects its corresponding argument to have type `int`; `pow` returns a `double`.  These types have different sizes and different representations - the binary representation of `123.0` (`double`) is *completely* different from the binary representation of `123` (`int`):

```
123   = 00 00 00 7b 
123.0 = 40 5e c0 00 00 00 00 00
```

Because of how `printf` is defined, it *doesn't know* the actual types of its arguments - it doesn't know that the argument corresponding to the result of `pow` is a `double` instead of an `int`.  Instead, it *expects* the first argument to be an `int` because you used `%d`, so it's not interpreting that value correctly.

Crank up your warnings on your compiler.